# How to show menu button to another page after login in ionic2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

Hello  I am developing mobile app and I successfully login then I switch another

page there I see back button not menu button. I have hidden back button but I want

show menu icon but it is not showing.How can I display a menu icon button after

successfully  login.I used **home.ts** for login.

```
doLogin(event) {    


        var user1 =this.loginForm.value;
        var password = this.loginForm.controls.password.value;
        this.homeService.doLogin(user1).subscribe(
            user =>{
                    this.user = user.results; 
                    this.navCtrl.push(DashboardComponent, {thing1: user });
                    //console.log(user);
                },
                err => {
                    console.log(err);
                },
                () => console.log('login complete')

            );
    }
```

here is another page display.html where I want display menu icon.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton="true">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
 <div id="login_image" >
  <div class="header padding text-center logodata">
    <img src="assets/images/big_logo.png" alt="Your logo here"  width="40%" height="auto" class="logoImage"/>
  </div>

  <div class="header padding text-center panda">
    <img src="assets/images/bear.png" alt="Your logo here" width="40%" height="auto" class="logobear"/>
  </div>

  <h1 class="getstarted" style="text-align:center">Get Started !</h1>
 </div>
        <div class="dashboardSection">

            <a href="">
                <div class="header padding text-center classes common">
                    <img src="assets/images/icos_15.png" alt="Your logo here"  width="50%" height="auto"/>
                    <p class="Sectiontitle">STUDENTS</p>
                </div>
            </a>


        </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: `ng-click` and `ng-controller` are angular 1 syntax.. you should be using angular 2+ for ionic 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the menu button instead of the back button, you'd need to set the HomePage as root (instead of just pushing it).

```
doLogin(event) {    
  var user1 =this.loginForm.value;
  var password = this.loginForm.controls.password.value;
  this.homeService.doLogin(user1).subscribe(
    user =>{
      this.user = user.results; 
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardComponent, {thing1: user }); // <- Here! :)
      //this.navCtrl.push(DashboardComponent, {thing1: user });
      //console.log(user);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    },
    () => console.log('login complete')
  );
}
```

And in the view you don't need to hide anything, since the back button won't be shown:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
...
</ion-content>
```

The main difference is that [`push`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#push) pushes another component onto the navigation stack (and that's why you can see the back button, and even go back to the previous page by using the physical back button in Android), whereas the [`setRoot`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#setRoot) set that component as the root of the navigation stack.

Also make sure that the `ion-menu` in your `app.html` file has the `persistent` attribute ([docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/menu/Menu/#persistent-menus)) like this:

```
<ion-menu persistent="true" [content]="mycontent">
  <ion-content>...</ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

Comment: Glad to help :)